# Maven cloudfoundry push routes are deleted

Tags: maven, routes, push, maven-plugin, cloud-foundry

If I push my webapp to cloudfoundry with the Cloud Foundry Maven Plugin (https://github.com/wdxxs2z/cloudfoundry-java-client-expend/tree/master/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin) all my routes are deleted. Is there a possiblity in maven to keep the mapped routes and to upload only the package or can I configure a route like 'subdomain.domain.com/mywebapp' for my deployed package in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both a `url` and `urls` properties are available in the pom to be consumed by push related tasks.

https://github.com/wdxxs2z/cloudfoundry-java-client-expend/blob/master/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/maven/AbstractApplicationAwareCloudFoundryMojo.java#L74